# Problem with copying code to clipboard using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is the code

```
echo https://www.bing.com/search?PC=U523&q=%random%&pglt=129&FORM=ANNTA1&DAF0=1|clip
```

The code copies the Microsoft Edge search link at random,using the `%random%` tool and the `clip` tool to copy the link to the clipboard.

The problem is that when I put the code in cmd I get this message

```
https://www.bing.com/search?PC=U523
'q' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'pglt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'FORM' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'DAF0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: give this a try @hack `echo https://www.bing.com/search?PC=U523^^^&q=%random%^^^&pglt=129^^^&FORM=ANNTA1^^^&DAF0=1|clip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in your code is the presence of ampersands `&`, which constitute [command concatenation operators](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Usually [escaping](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) special characters (like `^&`) is enough, but in this situation a [pipe `|`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) is involved, which instantiates new [`cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instances for either side<sup>1</sup>, which then receive unescaped characters. For this reason, you need to establish double-escaping, like this:

```cmd
echo https://www.bing.com/search?PC=U523^^^&q=%random%^^^&pglt=129^^^&FORM=ANNTA1^^^&DAF0=1| clip
```

However, composing escape sequences depending on whether or not pipes are involved is quite nasty, but there is a nice option, namely [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). For this, the string first obviously needs to be assigned to a variable:

```cmd
rem // Store string to variable; use quoted `set` syntax to protect special characters:
set "URL=https://www.bing.com/search?PC=U523&q=%random%&pglt=129&FORM=ANNTA1&DAF0=1"
rem // Explicitly instantiate a new `cmd.exe` instance with delayed expansion enabled:
cmd /V:ON /D /C echo(!URL!| clip
```

---

<sub>1)  No new instance is created for each side of the pipe that just contains a pure external command (like [`clip.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/clip.html)).</sub>